# Line 8: SyntaxError - bad input (' ')

Tags: python, syntax-error

Why is the top one not working, but the bottom one doing just fine? I think it's an issue with spaces, but it looks identical. What's the problem?

Broken code:

```
month = int(input("Enter the month: "))
day = int(input("Enter the day: "))

if (month == 9):
    if (day <= 15):
     print ("First half of the month")
    else:
     print ("Second half of the month") #The line with the error
else:
 print ("Not in September")
```

Working code:

```
month = int(input("Enter the month: "))
day = int(input("Enter the day: "))

if (month == 9):
    if (day <= 15):
     print ("First half of the month")
    else:
     print ("Second half of the month")
else:
 print ("Not in September")
```

Comment: "SyntaxError - bad input" isn't a kind of SyntaxError Python actually issues, as far as I'm aware, and the code you've posted displays no visible errors. Could you include the complete, exact error message in your question, including stack trace?

Comment: Depending on what's actually parsing the code, there won't be a stack trace, since the error occurs during parsing, not execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a invisible character ('non-standard' space) at the beginning of that line.

The character is an EM SPACE (U+2003) which seems identical to a normal space.

I found this by copying your code into notepad++ then going to view > show symbol and enabling 'show all characters'

Answer (score 1):

Your first code contains an em-space (Unicode code point 8195) rather than a space.